# How to dynamically remove a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html table like so -

```
<table class="table" id="myTable">
<thead>
   <th>Email</th>
   <th>Delete</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

I can dynamically add to the table doing this:

```
var tbody = $('#myTable').children('tbody');   
var table = tbody.length ? tbody : $('#myTable');
table.append("<tr><td>"+user_email+"</td><td><input type='button' value='Del' id ='"+user_id+"'class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'></td></tr>");
```

But when I try to remove a row doing this:

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function(e){
   $(this).closest('tr').remove()
})
```

The row don't remove. How do I resolve this?

Comment: do you need to remove all rows?

Comment: Just the one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close, since the TR and the button are dynamically generated,
use the [`.on()` method:](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#myTable").on("click", "input[type='button']", function(e){
   $(this).closest('tr').remove()
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work.

Comment: @radioactive what means "does not work" do you have any errors in console? IS your table also dynamically generated? The first selector should be a static parent, than the event name, and than goes a selector for your dynamic delete buttons. Not that complicated.

Comment: @radioactive and PS, use rather a descriptive class instead of `"input[type='button']"`

Comment: This is error on the console - Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined

Comment: @radioactive I changed the example since.... can you refresh this page?

Comment: I used a descriptive class as you recommended and it works now! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes *not* using jQuery may help you understand what's actually happening. Here's a snippet that may be helpful.

```js
// add the listener to the document (event delegation)
document.addEventListener("click", deleteRow);

// add a first row
addRow(document.querySelector("#myTable"));

function deleteRow(evt) {
  // read data-property (data-delete or data-add)
  if (evt.target.dataset.delete) {
    // retrieve the row to delete
    const row2Delete = evt.target.closest("tr");
    // remove that from *its parent* (the table)
    row2Delete.parentNode.removeChild(row2Delete);
  } else if (evt.target.dataset.add) {
    addRow(document.querySelector("#myTable"));
  }
  return true;
}

function addRow(toTable) {
  // create a row
  const row = document.createElement("tr");
  // create 2 cells
  const cell1 = document.createElement("td");
  const cell2 = cell1.cloneNode(true);
  //create a button for the second cell
  const bttn = document.createElement("button");
  bttn.dataset.delete = "1";
  bttn.textContent = "delete";
  // fill the first cell with a random e-mailaddress
  cell1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`someUser${
        Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 10000000)}@somewhere.net`));
  // append button to cell2        
  cell2.appendChild(bttn);
  // append cells to row
  row.appendChild(cell1);
  row.appendChild(cell2);
  // append row to table
  toTable.appendChild(row);
}
```

```html
<button data-add="1">Add a row</button>
<table class="table" id="myTable">
<thead>
   <th>Email</th>
   <th>Delete</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Is there any problem with my current JQuery?

Comment: Well [@Roko C Buljan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383904/roko-c-buljan) explained that already. Just liked to demonstrate that [you may not need jquery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) and sometimes doing things in plain vanilla js gives more understanding of what you or js are/is actually doing. But hey, do what you like best, I'm not imposing things here.